# Allow pull-down refresh when there is new activity

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Ordinarily, you can pull down on the question list in the app to refresh it. However, if there is the new activity message, pull down refresh doesn't work. Instead, you have to tap the bar to refresh.

I find this quite annoying. Very often i will mis-tap, and somehow end up with the search bar focused. It would make a lot of sense to be able to just pull down to refresh it. That's harder to mess up.

Comment: Are you using the alpha build or the app store build?

Comment: The alpha build, for iPad.

Comment: @BrianNickel This is still an issue in the App Store release and it's somewhat frustrating. Tap or pull down. One or the other please. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the feature request directly (it's an idea to ruminate on) but I fixed your problem with the search bar. Some things are a little dodgy when the new activity indicator first appears outside of a user interaction so your taps were actually getting sent to the search bar. There was a workaround in the 1.1.0 version of the app but it got lost in a reimplementation.  If you download the latest build it should be a lot easier to refresh.

Comment: I'm interested in the implementation of tap or pull down logic, any updates on that? Or a new feature request is necessary?