# Allow tapping outside iPad app popup to close it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, ipad, user-experience

To close a popup window in the iPad app `(1.2.0.141)`, you need to tap the Done button in the top left corner of the heading bar. It would be intuitive if the popup windows would also close if you tap on the faded background outside the window.

IMHO of course.

Comment: I've already asked about your second bullet point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241925/allow-pull-down-refresh-when-there-is-new-activity

Comment: @Scimonster Yay, then there is at least __two__ people in favor of the request! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modals (popups) can now be easily dismissed by tapping on the grey background. This change is available in beta version 1.2.0.146.