# Different action for page refresh

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

In some situation I need to "pull down" for refresh, in another - "tap" for refresh.

When question was edited by someone other I see this message on the top of question:

[image: tap to reload]

I can pull down here but nothing happen. I.e. I can't get edited version of question.

When I want to refresh list of question I see this one (after beginning of pulling down):

[image: pull down]

Also I need to "tap" on question list when connection is broken:

[image: no connection]

Is it possible to make it uniform (for example, pull down to refresh edited question)?

Related post: [Allow pull-down refresh when there is new activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/241925/339911)

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: I'm probably going to revisit this in iOS 11 since Apple's redone the native pull to refresh action.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your confusion but actually those two ways of refreshing have two separate purposes.

The one you have to pull down is non-intrusive because it is an action that can be performed, but the user actually doesn't really have to. It is totally free and optional.

The second one, that appears as a notification is a message and button in one: it tells you something important, like the loss of connection, and allows you to perform an action by clicking. Of course, that could have been a pull down too. I after that yoy should be able to pull down the second message, so maybe it is an option to allow both clicking and pulling in the second message.

Comment: Agree. I also told about possibility to `pull down` to refresh when notification appears. Not only for doing it by `tapping`.

Comment: Indeed. Improved wording.

Comment: What annoys me is that once the tap to refresh appears, pull down to refresh won't work any more... So they are teaching you one action and then preventing the use of it every time a question is asked/answered/edited. Seems like a UI issue to me.